# How to fix the second part from the code?

Tags: php, html, web

So I am working on a small project for my fathers business. I am done with the most part, but I still have to do some back-end development. I want the user to select some checkboxes and then see the fixed price from the selected (I am done with this), then the user types in their value and it multiplies by the fixed price given from the checkboxes.
Here is the code:

```
<?php
//first part             
if(isset( $_GET["choice"] )){             
  $food = $_GET["choice"];             
  $c = count($food);             
  $price = 0.0;                           
  for($i=0;$i<$c;$i++){                 
    if($food[$i] == 1){                     
       $price = $price + 10;                     
       echo "Вие избрахте:<br>";                     
       echo "Лепене на гипсокартон<br>";                 
    }                 
    if($food[$i] == 2){                     
       $price = $price + 12;                     
       echo "Предстенна обшивка 1 пласт<br>";                 
    }                 
    if($food[$i] == 3){                     
       $price = $price + 16;                     
       echo "Предстенна обшивка 2 пласта<br>";                 
    }                 
    if($food[$i] == 4){                     
       $price = $price + 18;                     
       echo "Преградна стена с вата<br>";                 
    }                 
    if($food[$i] == 5){                     
       $price = $price + 2;                     
       echo "Редене на минерална и каменна вата<br>";                 
    }             
  }            
  echo "<br>Общо за 1 кв/м: " .$price. "лв.<br>";             
}            
else{                 
   echo 'Моля изберете нещо!';             
}  
//second part           
echo "Въведете вашата квадратура     <input type='text'name='finalprice'method='get'>";
echo "<input type='submit' valu='Изчисли'>"             
$finalprice = $_GET["finalprice"];             
if($finalprice[$i]>= 1){                 
   $finalprice = $finalprice * $price;                 
   echo "За вашата квадратура: " .$finalprice;             
}
```

Comment: What is the problem in the second part?

Comment: When i try to run the code, php gives me this error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$finalprice' (T_VARIABLE), expecting ',' or ';' in E:\Joomla\xampp\xampp\htdocs\firmen-sait\calculator.php on line 38

Comment: `$finalprice` is not an array, so `$finalprice[$i]` will fail. (also $i would not be the right value anyway at this part, but just the leftover from above)

Comment: for your error: you forgot a `;` after `echo "<input type='submit' valu='Изчисли'>" `. And `valu` should probably be `value` here. In the line above: an input doesn't have a "method" attribute.

Comment: Man I say a way easier way to do this....

Comment: I am here and listening...

Comment: `I am here and listening.`  - Told you .... lol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a cleaner approach then what you are doing.

```
 //$choice = isset($_GET['choice']) && is_array($_GET['choice']) ? $_GET['choice'] : [];   
$choice = [2];

$map =  [
    1 => [               
       'price' => 10,                    
       'message' => "Вие избрахте:<br>Лепене на гипсокартон<br>",                
    ], 2 => [                             
       'price' => 12,                   
       'message' => "Предстенна обшивка 1 пласт<br>",                 
    ]
    //...
];

$food = array_intersect_key($map, array_flip($choice));  //choice is [2 => 0] after fliping

print_r($food);
$price = 0.0; 
foreach($food as $f){
    $price +=  $f['price']; 
    echo $f['message']."\n";
}

echo 'Price: '.$price;
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [2] => Array
        (
            [price] => 12
            [message] => Предстенна обшивка 1 пласт<br>
        )

)
Предстенна обшивка 1 пласт<br>
Price: 12
```

[Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e0685b757757b853a52f2a76c3ca6b2f8ae5fb54)

This will work provided you can **only make each choice once** and that I guessed the input data correctly.  It looks like choice could be an array with `1-5` as the values, but I don't know if you can have duplicate values.  If so the `array_flip` will remove them, so we cant use that or `array_intersect_key`.  If that is the case we may be able to do some tricks with `array_count_values`

**UPDATE**

Here is a modification that will handle duplicate choices:

*I never used `array_count_values` this way before, but it fell right into place in my mind. So I figured I would post that too.*

```
 //$choice = isset($_GET['choice']) && is_array($_GET['choice']) ? $_GET['choice'] : [];        
$choice = [2,2,2];

$map =  [
    1 => [               
       'price' => 10,                    
       'message' => "Вие избрахте:<br>Лепене на гипсокартон<br>",                
    ],2 => [                             
       'price' => 12,                   
       'message' => "Предстенна обшивка 1 пласт<br>",                 
    ]
];

//we need to modify this for later use (multiplication)
$choice = array_count_values($choice);  //changes to [2 => 3] or [value => number of]
//so we get the same effect as array_flip, changing the value to the key
//we need it the key so we can match it to $map's Key
//- but with this we know how many times that item was checked

$food = array_intersect_key($map, $choice); 

print_r($food);
$price = 0.0; 
foreach($food as $k=>$f){
    $price +=  ($f['price'] * $choice[$k]); 
    echo $f['message']."\n";
}

echo 'Price: '.$price;
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [2] => Array
        (
            [price] => 12
            [message] => Предстенна обшивка 1 пласт<br>
        )

)
Предстенна обшивка 1 пласт<br>
Price: 36  #here we have 3 that are 12 each so we expect 36
```

[Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/6e5b916ed75a70a60812d05a0e106de64d16f182)

One other small effect of using `array_count_values` is we are looping over less data.  In the above example instead of looping 3 times, we actually only do 1 iteration.  At most you would do up to the count of the `$map` array iterations.  It's not a huge performance boost for something as simple as this, but it's there.

Both of these are much cleaner implementations, because if you need to add a choice with your old code that required adding in another `if` block and a bunch of code.  With this way you just create another array of data, which happens to be something you could even store in a Database if you wanted to.

I should add I was to "lazy" to convert all your data to an array, so you will have to add the other `3` or so in there.

*-Note-*  I thought about removing the first method as the second one is better, but I will leave it as it shows another way to do the same basic thing...

If you wanted to save the pricing data in the DB (which is something I would probably do), you would make a table with

```
 id | price | message
```

And then store that data in the table, and pull it out with something like `PDO` using `fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_GROUP)` so you get the ID as the key ... etc ... but that is up to you and outside the scope of the question.  I just thought I would mention it as an advantage of using an array.

In any case, Enjoy!